# Arvei Nahal - Acceptable Species

Tags: halacha, science, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, agriculture, hoshana-rabbah

Vayikra 23:40 provides the commandment to take up the four species on Sukkot: וּלְקַחְתֶּם לָכֶם בַּיּוֹם הָרִאשׁוֹן פְּרִי עֵץ הָדָר כַּפֹּת תְּמָרִים וַעֲנַף עֵץ עָבֹת וְעַרְבֵי נָחַל וּשְׂמַחְתֶּם לִפְנֵי יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵיכֶם שִׁבְעַת יָמִים - "And ye shall take you on the first day the fruit of *Hadar* tree, branches of date palms, and bough of *'avot* tree, and **willows of the brook**, and ye shall rejoice before the L-RD your G-d seven days."

The [Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayyim 647:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.647.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) [hattip: @danf], basing himself on [Maimonides](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Shofar%2C_Sukkah_and_Lulav.7.3?lang=bi&with=Sukkah&lang2=he), seems to restrict the usable species to specific known *minim*/*min*.

According to contemporary *poskim*, which genera/species of plants might be usable as "עַרְבֵי נָחַל"?

For example, are there any halachic issues with using branches of the common ornamental [weeping willow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_babylonica)?

What about the controversial [Euphrates poplar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus_euphratica), identified by some historians as the עֲרָבִים of Psalms 137:2, but by others as the explicitly excluded [צפצפה](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.3.3?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)? (See also [Sukkah 34a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.34a.9?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en).)

Comment: Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayyim 647:1 speaks about an alternate species that is kosher. However, I have trouble translating what he is referring to. If you can translate, that would help form an answer. AFAIK, the weeping willow MAY be usable. IIRC, I have seen people use this in the past. It tends to grow next to streams / lakes.

Comment: http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?id=130