# Popular Contemporary Aravoth Species

Tags: minhag, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hoshana-rabbah, hoshanos

[Vayikra 23:40](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0323.htm#40) provides the commandment to take up the 4 species on Sukkot:

> וּלְקַחְתֶּ֨ם לָכֶ֜ם בַּיּ֣וֹם הָֽרִאשׁ֗וֹן פְּרִ֨י עֵ֤ץ הָדָר֙ כַּפֹּ֣ת תְּמָרִ֔ים וַֽעֲנַ֥ף עֵץ־עָבֹ֖ת **וְעַרְבֵי־נָ֑חַל** וּשְׂמַחְתֶּ֗ם לִפְנֵ֛י יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹֽהֵיכֶ֖ם שִׁבְעַ֥ת יָמִֽים׃
>
> "And ye shall take you on the first day the fruit of *Hadar* tree, branches of date palms, and bough of *'avot* tree, and **willows of the brook**, and ye shall rejoice before the L-RD your G-d seven days."

What is/are the biological species of "עַרְבֵי נָחַל" most commonly used/sold today for the *arba minim*  and *hoshanoth* (e.g. in the U.S. and/or Israel)?

Related: [Arvei Nahal - Acceptable Species](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61260/arvei-nahal-species)

Comment: "Monsey Aravos" are popular- do you refer to them?

Answer (score 1):

Aravot are generally considered to be Salix alba, also called [white willow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_alba) .

Source: [Do Aravot grow berries?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137178/do-aravot-grow-berries) answered by Yaacov Deane

Comment: @YaakovDeane using ur answer

Comment: However this is a tree. Do aravot grow as a bush too?