# Do Aravot grow berries?

Tags: sukkah, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I know that Hadasim can grow berries, but what about the accepted specie of Aravot. Does it grow berries at some point?

I have heard the dvar Torah about fruit (smell/taste), but that only works if Hadassim are not counted due to the berry, if so Aravot could still have berries and work with that vort.

Interestingly I see that there are halachos about the berries and hadassim, but not Aravos. Can anyone confirm there are no berries by Aravos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aravot are generally considered to be Salix Alba, White Willow.

They reproduce via what look like small berries at the leave nodes called *catkins*.

If the willow is healthy and thriving, they look visually like small berries and are filled with very tiny seeds, like fruit would be.

I can report from personal experience that aphids love these things as they ripen, but they are not like actual fruit that one would consider like food. They only serve the willow for reproduction.

On that note, there is discussion in Midrash of a change that will occur at some point during the days of Moshiach. That certain plants that previously bore no fruit, will start to manifest fruit.

These *miraculous fruit* are called *gluska’ote* in addition to the other type of gluska’ote mentioned in the Torah which were incredibly large, flavorful and aromatic. Accordingly to the reports from Midrash, these fruits will have miraculous curative properties.

Here is a link detailing the white willow: [white willow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_alba)

Comment: Wonderful this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.